# C# TryParseExact CultureInfo.InvariantCulture Changing behavior when culture change

Tags: c#, parsing, date, datetime

I am trying to convert date with the following format `"d/MM/yyyy"`

example :

> - 5/11/2014
> - 12/12/2013
> - 31/01/2012

I am using TryParseExact method :

```
private const string DateFormat = "d/MM/yyyy";
Culture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
DateTime creationDateConverted;
DateTime.TryParseExact(creationDate, DateFormat, Culture, 
            DateTimeStyles.None, out creationDateConverted);
```

**The display method is** :

```
@Html.DisplayFor(m => object.date)

date having :  DisplayFormat( DataFormatString="{0:d/MM/yyyy}")
```

The server which host the website has a US culture.

if I set the culture to fr-FR using Web.config it works well.

But if I don't set that culture it does not work, it convert it do MM/dd/yyyy format and of course some date don't pass with that format.

I don't understand why the culture would have influence on that method because I provide a specific format and a culture invariant.

I also tried to provide a Culture fr-Fr to the method but no luck

**EDIT :** when I say fail, I means that the TryParseExact Method return false

Comment: Note that you posted parsing code, but asking why it is formatted based on current culture without showing formatting code.

Comment: If it's not absolutely mandatory to display a date in any kind of localised format, it might be a good idea to display it in [ISO 8601](http://www.iso.org/iso/home/standards/iso8601.htm) format: yyyy-MM-dd.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with this parsing code, it is culture invariant. How are you interrogating the result, i.e. seeing what `creationDateConverted` is set to?

Comment: Hi jodrell, actually TryParseExact return false and set creationDateConverted to MinValue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DateTime has no format. And the ToString method output depend on the culture.

If you want a specific format use this :

```
creationDateConverted.ToString("d/MM/yyyy");
```

Comment: "If you want a specific format use this" - your example isn't unambiguous because it uses the culture-specific date separator "/".  For example, in a German culture, this will be rendered as ".".  You should add an argument CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.

Comment: Hi thanks, I am using a DisplayFormat with "d/MM/yyyy" so I don't thing it is the problem

Comment: Hi actually the problem was the creationDate which had a different format on the server so your solution is valid. Thanks you everyone !

Answer (score 0):

The parsing code you have posted is unaffected by any external culture setting.

However, the culture could effect what happens when you interrogate the value of the `DateTime` `creationDateConverted`.

Comment: Hi, thanks I have putted the code that display the date but there is something wrong with the my code because the server failed to convert some date (I have added log to check whenever it fail or not)